# How to add a local file to trusted zone in IE8?

Tags: security, internet-explorer-8

I want to add a file on my local drive (C:\something.html) to the Trusted Zone in IE8 (my OS is Windows Server 2003). The Add Sites Dialog box, does not seem to take entries for files on the local drive.

I have tried:

```
file://C:\something.html
file:\\localhost\c$\something.html
```

I have seen other solutions (on superuser and elsewhere) such Mark of Web, that allow your local file to be treated as if it were part of the internet zone, but I want to add my file to the Trusted Zone.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I haven’t used IE for a while now, so I don’t know if they changed it, but aren’t all local files (ie My Computer) in the Trusted Zone already?

Comment: In IE9 and IE11, I can see that a local file is considered to be in the *Internet* security zone. In IE8, it is in *Local Computer* zone (it's hidden from the security settings dialog).

Answer (score 10):

In Internet Explorer, go to

```
Tools → Internet Options → Advanced
```

Scroll down to the Security section and check the box for

```
Allow active content to run in files on My Computer
```

Comment: You have to restart Windows, too.

Answer (score 2):

Dangerous suggestion :
Install IIS, add C: as a virtual directory, and add localhost to the Trusted Zone.

You can set the permissions to allow IIS access only to some of the directories on C:.

The only other solution I know is [Mark of the Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx).

For example:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0023)http://www.contoso.com/ -->
```